# Обновление данных аккаунта telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Нужно изменить настройки конфидециальности и аватарку `telegram` аккаунта в `python` коде с помощью `telethon`. Можно предложить другие библиотеки которые помогут мне сделать это. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какие настройки конфиденциальности? Аватар -https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/set_profile_photo#pyrogram.Client.set_profile_photo, профиль - https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/update_profile#pyrogram.Client.update_profile, ник -https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/update_username#pyrogram.Client.update_username ., Так же есть методы для блокировки пользователей, установки облачного пароля.

Answer (score 3):

Можете поменять свой ник:

```
app.update_username("my_new_username")
```

Так же свое имя и фамилию:

```
app.update_profile(first_name="my_new_first_name")

app.update_profile(last_name="my_new_last_name")
```

Свой аватар:

```
app.set_profile_photo(photo="my_new_photo.jpg")
```